# Migration from Jboss AS7 to wildfly 9 - how to configure so that the site can be accessed without "www" in front

Tags: java, jboss

We just upgraded the our web application to Java1.8 and web server to wildfly 9.0.1,  from Java 1.7 and Jboss AS7.
All works fine except one that the web application is not accessible simply by "somedomain.com". I have to type "www.somedomain.com".

The Jboss AS7 had the followings in the standalone.xml;

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
    <alias name="localhost"/>
    <alias name="somedomain.com"/>
    <alias name="www.somedomain.com"/>
    <rewrite pattern="^(.*)$" substitution="https://www.somedomain.com$1" flags="R=301,L">
        <condition test="%{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^somedomain\.com$" flags="NC"/>
    </rewrite>
</virtual-server>
```

Where do I put this in the wildfly's configuration?

My servers are Windows 2012.

Answer (score 0):

To get multiple aliases working, configure it like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.2">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
        <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost,somedomain.com,www.somedomain.com">
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config/>
        <websockets/>
    </servlet-container>
    <handlers>
        <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
    </handlers>
    <filters>
        <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/8"/>
        <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```

Unfortunately you can't do your URL rewriting with Wildfly. The undertow subsystem does not have rewriting exposed via the configuration. See this thread: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/236258?_sscc=t